# How can I get multipe columns from sub-query? [Error] Execution (167: 13): ORA-00913: too many values

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run the query below I get an error: `ORA-00913: too many values`

Is there any other way to get multiple values with in sub-query or as a part of one big query?

Thanks in advance!

```sql
SELECT ID,
  CASENO,
  CASE
    WHEN PMT_METHOD = 'B'
    THEN
      (SELECT ROUTE_TRANS || CHK_DIGIT FROM BANK_MASTER WHERE BANK_ID = BANK_ID
      )
  END AS ROUTING_NUMBER,
  (SELECT ADDR1,
    ADDR2,
    CITY,
    ADD_STATE,
    ZIP
  FROM DB.clientref,
    DB.client_address
  WHERE addressid = address_id
  AND addresstype = 'L'
  AND disabled    = 'N'
  AND inv_id      = 'ADMIN'
  AND CLTID       = CLIENTID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CA_ADDR1,
    CA_ADDR2,
    CA_CITY,
    CA_STATE,
    CA_ZIP
  FROM DB.clientref,
    DB.client_address
  WHERE addressid = address_id
  AND addresstype = 'L'
  AND disabled    = 'N'
  AND CLTID       = CLIENTID
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM DB.clientref,
      DB.client_address
    WHERE addressid = address_id
    AND addresstype = 'L'
    AND disabled    = 'N'
    AND inv_id      = 'ADMIN'
    AND CLTID       = CLIENTID ) = 0
  AND ROWNUM        = 1
  )
FROM DUMMY_REQUESTS,
WHERE ID = '1234'
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN the subquery instead.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with both MySQL and Oracle?

Comment: In Oracle 12C, you can use a lateral join.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow.  I apologize to add oracle if I am not supposed to.  I added it as I am using oracle database. @NicoHaase

Comment: Thanks guys for the help.  Let me give it a try and see if that works.

Comment: You need to rethink this. You do not need to return multiple rows from your sub-query. As it current stands it returns the transit-routing number for every bank in the **Bank_Master** table. Your where clause "WHERE BANK_ID = BANK_ID"  is true for every row. If one of those is  a parameter you need to change the name.